# Logstash not reading file input using docker-compose.yaml file

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, logstash, kibana

logstash.conf file:

```
 input {

 file {
    type => "java"
    path => "/elk/spring-boot-elk.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}


filter {
  #If log line contains tab character followed by 'at' then we will tag that entry as 
stacktrace
  if [message] =~ "\tat" {
    grok {
      match => ["message", "^(\tat)"]
      add_tag => ["stacktrace"]
    }
  }

}

output { 
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }

  # Sending properly parsed log events to elasticsearch
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
  }
}
```

`docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.5.2
    ports: 
    - "9200:9200"
    - "9300:9300"
    environment:
    - discovery.type=single-node
  kibana:
    image: kibana:7.5.2
    ports:
    - "5601:5601"
    links:
    - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
    - elasticsearch
  logstash:
    image: logstash:7.5.2
    links:
    - elasticsearch
    volumes:
    - ./:/config-dir
    command: logstash -f /config-dir/logstash.conf
    depends_on:
    - elasticsearch
```

All containers are running but there is no data present on `kibana`.

I think the issue is with `logstash`.

> ```
> [2020-04-26T16:37:44,502][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] You are using a deprecated config setting "document_type" set in elasticsearch. Deprecated settings will continue to work, but are scheduled for removal from logstash in the future. Document types are being deprecated in Elasticsearch 6.0, and removed entirely in 7.0. You should avoid this feature If you have any questions about this, please visit the #logstash channel on freenode irc. {:name=>"document_type", :plugin=><LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch bulk_path=>"/_monitoring/bulk?system_id=logstash&system_api_version=7&interval=1s", hosts=>[http://elasticsearch:9200], sniffing=>false, manage_template=>false, id=>"7d7dfa0f023f65240aeb31ebb353da5a42dc782979a2bd7e26e28b7cbd509bb3", document_type=>"%{[@metadata][document_type]}", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_1a08e50c-ae97-4f38-a5b7-7aa70df94f4a", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, workers=>1, template_name=>"logstash", template_overwrite=>false, doc_as_upsert=>false, script_type=>"inline", script_lang=>"painless", script_var_name=>"event", scripted_upsert=>false, retry_initial_interval=>2, retry_max_interval=>64, retry_on_conflict=>1, ilm_enabled=>"auto", ilm_rollover_alias=>"logstash", ilm_pattern=>"{now/d}-000001", ilm_policy=>"logstash-policy", action=>"index", ssl_certificate_verification=>true, sniffing_delay=>5, timeout=>60, pool_max=>1000, pool_max_per_route=>100, resurrect_delay=>5, validate_after_inactivity=>10000, http_compression=>false>}
> [2020-04-26T16:37:44,544][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
> [2020-04-26T16:37:44,550][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
> [2020-04-26T16:37:44,555][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
> [2020-04-26T16:37:44,555][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
> [2020-04-26T16:37:44,586][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["http://elasticsearch:9200"]}
> [2020-04-26T16:37:44,597][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>".monitoring-logstash", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>2, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>2, "pipeline.sources"=>["monitoring pipeline"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x61a1055 run>"}
> [2020-04-26T16:37:44,636][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>".monitoring-logstash"}
> [2020-04-26T16:37:44,654][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>2, :running_pipelines=>[:main, :".monitoring-logstash"], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
> [2020-04-26T16:37:44,899][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
> ```

Comment: In the default mode 'tail' logstash expects that the file gets constantly written to. So you may want to test the configuration while adding new lines to the file. Or you switch to read-mode. In this mode you have to set some other required settings as well. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-mode for reference.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? If so please post the answer